# Thunderbird and fiber optic upgrade

Tags: windows-7, email, thunderbird

I am with ATT in Houston.  Recently my neighborhood received fiber and I upgraded.

I tested Internet, phone, and TV.  Did not think to test email.  Somehow email broke.  Thunderbird takes like 30 seconds to time out and I get an error message server returned an error.  If I use the browser (mail.yahoo.com) I get email.  I even get test messages I sent to myself from Thunderbird. I have an email in mail.yahoo.com invalid device identified and blocked and ATT claims to have removed the block.

Exact message:
Sending of password for user xxxyyy@att.net did not succeed. Mail server inbound.att.net responded: Server error - Please try again later.

I installed the latest upgrade to Thunderbird.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: What exactly is the returned error message?

Comment: @harrymc I updated the question.

Comment: Try the checks in [this article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/cannot-send-messages).

Comment: Which Operating System do you use?  It may help to suggest debug procedures.

Comment: @AnFi Windows 7

Comment: @harrymc That help is old.  There is no longer a tools menu.

Comment: You should contact AT&T.  This appears to be a DNS issue.  I am going to guess that your inbound server address changed.  Only AT&T could confirm that

Comment: @Ramhound ATT spent some time with me and then claimed not their problem.   It was a very frustrating.  I an ping the server.

Comment: That old article suggested several checks that are worth doing. If all of them come up negative, then this would be a problem with your ISP.

Comment: @harrymc ATT is my ISP.  I verified all the settings.

Comment: I've gone through similar symptoms with other providers.  It isn't Thunderbird.  However, Thunderbird can often fix it.  Create a new email account and let Thunderbird's wizard find the account settings.  If that doesn't fix it, verify those settings against what ATT gave you, including port numbers.  It wouldn't hurt to add the complete list of settings you're using to the question (mask your personal information).  If that doesn't fix it, create a secure email key/password as harrymc suggests.

Comment: BTW, sometimes, setting changes don't take immediate effect if the account is already open.  It can't hurt to restart Thunderbird after making changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using ATT and cannot test, but according to all the user testimonies
I have read, calling ATT Support does not solve the problem.
Here are some suggestions for what worked for some people:

1. Sign into your AT&T Webmail account, sometimes it helps.
2. Increasing the send/receive to 15 minutes or try on hours of low traffic,
   will tell if the problem is ATT traffic congestion.
3. [Create a secure mail key](https://www.att.com/esupport/article.html#!/email-support/KM1240308?gsi=omVXcTU) (profile->sign-in info->secure mail key) and use it in place of your POP/IMAP and smtp server password.
   For more information see also the items marked as solution on these posts:

   - [Unable to receive e-mail thru thunderbird](https://forums.att.com/t5/AT-T-Internet-Email-Security/UNABLE-TO-RECEIVE-E-MAIL-THRU-THUNDERBIRD/td-p/5632387)
   - [Sending of password for user @bellsouth.net did not succeed](https://forums.att.com/t5/AT-T-Internet-Email-Security/Need-Help-quot-Sending-of-password-for-user-bellsouth-net-did/td-p/5239473)
4. Do this [ATT Troubleshooting](https://forums.att.com/t5/AT-T-Internet-Email-Security/Email-Not-Working-Troubleshooting-Information-from-AT-amp-T/td-p/5052850).